# What to do with multiple successive edits when reviewing

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

There is a review with the tag 'x' and some lengthy explanation of that tag which is ok and I approve it. Then, going to the next review I see the same tag again, with even the same edit, but only a short version of it.

Something like:

Tag 'X'

X is a library from Y which is used to blabla .....

And on the next review its like:

Tag 'X'

X is a library from Y.

I always wonder, what happens if I approve both? Is the long version then replaced by the short version? Is the second one, some edit that was done by the same user and he expanded on it later, but the review algorithm presented them in the wrong order? I suppose the second edit should be rejected in such a case, right?

I just wanted to know what to do in such case, and if this is a bug, or what it means, or am I doing something wrong here?

Even though I noticed this with some regular questions as well, this is rather rare. It happens frequently on Wiki edits though.

As an example I mean such a case (long):

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3678417

And this (short):

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3678418

Just had another case like this:
[Long version](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3678667)
[Short version](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3678668)

Don't know if this is coincidence that it is even the same user again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short one is the tag wiki excerpt

[image]

and the long one is the tag wiki

[image]

They are different things...

Comment: Thx, I was not aware of that difference.